# Using a symlinked module on Windows with Python

Tags: python, windows, windows-7, symlink, ntfs

Currently I've got a symlinked directory of a python module I want in the same directory as my file, however when my python script tries to `import pyamf` python raises an `ImportError: No module named pyamf`.

When copying the directory it works fine, so it's something to do with the symlink (which was created with windows' `mklink` command rather than msys `ln`)

Python is version 2.7.2 x64

Comment: How are you running the script?  What directory are you starting it from?

Comment: I can't speak to Python directly on this one, but I know that PHP does not recognize those as actual directories. Even though Windows claims they should work the same way, they don't.

Comment: I'm running it from the standard Windows Command Prompt, from the same directory as the script and the module is stored in. e.g. just `python script.py`

Comment: mklink does not create a link. It requires options and two parameters. If you don't tell us what the problem is, we can only guess...

Answer (score 3):

Python 2.7 has problems with Windows symlinks. Instead of making a sym-link, make a directory junction using the `\J` option. For example:

```
mklink \J link_dir target_dir
```